# Color Changing Progress Bars in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

So, I have a DataGridView and in this table there is text and the last column is a Progess Bar showing a percentage. I've implemented a modified version of the DataGridViewProgressCell that I found (if I remember correctly) MSDN somewhere. The source code for this implementation is below.

```
    public class DataGridViewProgressColumn : DataGridViewImageColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewProgressColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewProgressCell();
        }
    }
    public class DataGridViewProgressCell : DataGridViewImageCell
    {
        // Used to make custom cell consistent with a DataGridViewImageCell
        static Image emptyImage;
        static DataGridViewProgressCell()
        {
            emptyImage = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        }
        public DataGridViewProgressCell()
        {
            this.ValueType = typeof(int);
        }
        protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return emptyImage;
        }

        protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics g, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            double progressVal = 0.0;

            if (value != null)
                progressVal = Convert.ToDouble(this.Value);

            float percentage = ((float)progressVal / 100.0f); // Need to convert to float before division; otherwise C# returns int which is 0 for anything but 100%.
            Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
            Brush foreColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.ForeColor);
            // Draws the cell grid
            base.Paint(g, clipBounds, cellBounds,
             rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText,
             cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, (paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground));
            if (percentage > 0.0)
            {
                // Draw the progress bar and the text
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(163, 189, 242)), cellBounds.X + 2, cellBounds.Y + 2, Convert.ToInt32((percentage * cellBounds.Width - 4)), cellBounds.Height - 4);
                g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
            }
            else
            {
                // draw the text
                if (this.DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index == rowIndex)
                    g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(cellStyle.SelectionForeColor), cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
                else
                    g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

And it makes a nice little Progress Bar in my DataGridView. There's only one problem... I can't figure out how to change the color of that progress bar **based on a range of the value**, and this value can change based on the type of report generated for the DataGridView. For example, in one report if the percentage is under 50%, it needs to be red, between 50-80%, yellow, and above 80%, green, but in a different report the thresholds might be 40% and 70%. I cannot figure out how to pass in these values to the DataGridViewProgressCell. My implementation is below. Thank you for any help!

```
    private void fillData()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Header1", "Header1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Header2", "Header2");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Header3", "Header3");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Header4", "Header4");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewProgressColumn());

        try
        {
            //jsonManager is a simple WebClient. Nothing fancy
            //The data is in a JSON format, first part of code handles getting the values needed for the table.
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string getData = serverURL + "/data";

            string htmlGET = jsonManager.DownloadString(getData);
            object[] myVals = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(htmlGET);

            Dictionary<string, object> overall = (Dictionary<string, object>)myVals[0];


            for (int i = 0; i < myVals .Length; i++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> entry = (Dictionary<string, object>)myVals [i];
                string fooHeader = "";
                double percent = Convert.ToDouble(entry["percent"]);
                int acceptable = (int)entry["acceptable"];
                int total_foo = (int)entry["total_welds"];

                if (i == 0)
                    sch = "OverallFoo";
                else
                    sch = ((int)entry["fooHeader"]).ToString();

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { sch, percent, acceptable, total_welds, percent });
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Handle exception(s)
        }
        finally
        {
           //More steps, including log writing.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then we just need a place to store the percentages that determine color of the progress bar. And then use it in the Paint() method. Here is what I would do:

I added two properties to your ProgressColumn:

```
public class DataGridViewProgressColumn : DataGridViewImageColumn
{
    public float RedUntil { get; set; }
    public float YellowUntil { get; set; }

    public DataGridViewProgressColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewProgressCell();
    }
}
```

Then I changed your cell drawing code:

```
        var progressColumn = this.DataGridView.Columns[this.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewProgressColumn;

        if (percentage > 0.0 && progressColumn != null)
        {
            // Draw the progress bar and the text
            Brush fillColor;
            if (percentage < progressColumn.RedUntil)
            {
                fillColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            }
            else if (percentage < progressColumn.YellowUntil)
            {
                fillColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
            }
            else
            {
                fillColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            }

            g.FillRectangle(fillColor, cellBounds.X + 2, cellBounds.Y + 2, Convert.ToInt32((percentage * cellBounds.Width - 4)), cellBounds.Height - 4);
            g.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
        }
        else
```

And that's how you use it:

```
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewProgressColumn { RedUntil = 0.5f, YellowUntil = 0.75f });
```

Comment: You, @markus-luedin, are a wonderful human being. Thank you! I've been bashing my head against this for a few days and I knew the solution was simple.